# 'Self' Validation Expressions in JSON file (karate framework)

Tags: karate

I have two questions concerning 'Self' Validation Expressions:

- Question1

In my feature I have

```
* def isStatus = function(s) { return s ==='SUCCESS' || s ==='ERROR' }
And match response[0] contains { status: '#? isStatus(_)' }
```

I would like to do this for every item of response like (* instead of 0):

```
And match response[*] contains { status: '#? isStatus(_)' }
```

But it doesn't work? Is anything is wrong?

I can't do this without js function like in this example:

```
* def date = { month: 3 }
* match date == { month: '#? _ > 0 && _ < 13' }
```

This doesn't work > `And match response[*] contains { status: '#? _ == 'SUCCESS' || _ == 'ERROR'' }`

- Question 2:

I have a json file where I would like to store response types. But when I use 'Self' Validation Expressions in my JSON file it doesn't work?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the documentation for `match each`. try this:

```
And match each response contains { status: '#? isStatus(_)' }
```

not able to understand q 2, please ask separately.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't finished my question and posted it. i'm sorry, i'l do it in another post.